# Is it inappropriate here to encourage someone to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

We have a recent user who is asking very nice questions almost everyday. I say nice because they are being received well by the community and attract answers that also receive quite some up-votes.

However out of 20+ questions the said user has not even accepted an answer on any one of them. Maybe the OP is not aware of it?

A few days ago I posted a comment on one of his questions to that effect and it was removed by a moderator (I don't mind, they would be right).

Is it inappropriate to encourage the OP to accept an answer? specially on questions that appear to be helpful to future readers and receive good votes.

It's not really about me receiving a green tick, its about the fact that when a new visitor comes to SE on a post the first thing they are usually looking for on a question is that green tick, then they start reading the answers. At least that is how i joined it long ago. Those Green ticks gave me instant guidance.

Comment: It's a bit of a hangover from old SO practice - where users would be notified by the system if the hadn't accepted many answers.
Then they removed the notices. Go figure. Each to their own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questioners who never accept answers are a chronic complaint all across SE, not far behind unexplained downvotes and answers placed in comments. Early on, there was the broad question *[How do you react to an apparently uninterested questioner?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234)* and then more specifically, the canonical ***[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994)*** There have been proposals like *[Comments saying "thank you" remind OP to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177292)* and *[Can moderators make an answer accepted to close the post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262672)* (at MSO) over the years.

There are also dozens of duplicate and related questions from *[Is it bad form to prompt new questioners to formally accept your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12543)* to *[Asking for someone to accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535)* to *[Is it ok to tell the OP to accept an upvoted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140256)*, and at MSO, *[Novice awareness of the accept feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276871)* and *[Encourage users to accept answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313206)*.

**Users aren't *required* to accept answers,** if they believe no answer is useful or complete enough for their needs. But I would venture that it is much more **common that a new user is unaware** there is even an option to accept a single answer. In such a case, I like the approach suggested in the top-voted answers to the MSO question *[Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288)*: **a polite comment nudging them** to choose an answer, perhaps with a link to *[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)*.

Some say they would only do this if the newbie has posted a comment to the effect of "yes, this was what I needed!" and others only if done so on answers other than their own. I would leave that to the individual community members and their comfort level; we are not one of the stacks where the participants are overly concerned about "rep-whoring."